# The size of Checkbox is changing when clicked

Tags: asp.net, html

when i click the checkbox on the page the size of the text will also change.
I used firebug and i noticed that there is an element.style that made the size changed..

Here is my code in html

```
 <td align="left">

 7.<asp:CheckBox 
 ID="chk18_7" runat="server"  
 Text="Ambulation" Enabled="False" />
```

this is my css

```
.style3
        {
            font-size: 10px;
        }
```

and this is the code i've got in firebug

```
<td align="left">
7.
<span class="aspNetDisabled style3" style="font-size:15px">
<input id="chk18_7" type="checkbox" onclick="return false;" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" name="chk18_7">
<label for="chk18_7">Ambulation</label>
</span>
</td>
```

how can i remove the  style="font-size:15px"

Thanks.

Comment: You sure the HTMl is from the same control? I ask because the code has ID chk18_7 while the actual HTML was for chk18_2. And, I'm thinking that some style was overridden on the ASP.NET Control causing the font-size attribute to get included.

Comment: i copied the wrong code..i updated it..please check..

Comment: What control/construct are you using to get style3 onto the span?

Comment: I just tested this in visual studio and no inline styles were being added to checkboxes.  You must have some validators or javascript that is applying those

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems you may have a validator or some kind of javascript applying an inline style, you can adjust the styling of the label by adding this to your stylesheet:

`span.aspNetDisabled.style3 label {font-size:10px !important}`

Comment: This solution isn't removing the style but is just creating a new one that would be applied to the label.  You maybe able to just get by with `.style3 label` which is what you may want to try first.